# Do PDO (non-emulated) statements keep track of earlier statements?

Tags: mysql, pdo

In other words, are the scenarios different performance-wise?

**A:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $pdo->prepare("SELECT :foo;")->execute(['foo' => 'test']);
}
```

**B:**

```
$sth    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :foo;");

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $sth->execute(['foo' => 'test']);
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone down-vote this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, pdo don't have such cache mechanism, in scenario A, you are creating pdo statement every time.